# Graphql base64 image data and Gastby

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby, gatsby-image, gatsby-plugin

Starting this gatsby site and i have data that come from remote PIM software.
The response :

```
"data": {
  "pim": {
    "getProducts": {
        "name": "000F office grey jeans",
        "image": {
          "mimetype": "image/jpeg",
          "type": "image",
          "data": "/9j/2wCEAAQDAwMDAwQDAwQGBAMEBgcFBA  .....
```

The question is if there is a plugin or a more friendly way to display image on Gatsby without have to compose the image src attribute i.e :

```
<img src="data:{data.pim.getProducts.image.mimetype};base64,{data.pim.getProducts.image.data}
```

I tried with StaticImage, GatsbyImage, getImage through

```
import { StaticImage, GatsbyImage, getImage} from 'gatsby-plugin-image'
```

but could not display the image on site.
Im using gatsby-source-graphql plugin.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to use `GatsbyImage` because to use it, Gatsby needs to treat the asset with its transformers and sharps to create the proper GraphQL node data (`gatsbyImageData`). In your case, the image is a base64 encoded string and can't be locally analyzed, hence it's not an option as is.

Regarding the `StaticImage`, I'm afraid it only works with URL paths, not in base64-like assets.

I don't see anything wrong with your `<img>` tag, but of course you're free to use any third-party dependency to lazy-load or to recreate the performances that Gatsby does with images when builds the site.

Comment: Thanks Ferran. Can you specify little bit more about "use any third-party dependency to lazy-load or to recreate the performances that Gatsby does with images" ...i need an example. I start gastby tutorial yesterday. :)

Comment: You won't be able to use Gatsby given the specs of your PIM response. Besides, there's nothing wrong with using your  `<img>` tag as you are doing but if you want to "fake" the blurry effect that Gatsby Image adds you can use a third party dependency like: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-lazy-blur-image or another one. It's up to you.